# I can't open Virtual Box on windows 10 after the Microsoft update on 9/21/2016

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I can't open Virtual Box on windows 10 after the Microsoft automatic update on 9/21/2016.

I get this error with vagrant up:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'scotch/box' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'aborted' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

Trying to start VM with the windows app and it does nothing. No errors, no VM

Does anyone else have this problem?

Is there a way to update VM on windows with re-installing?

Comment: System Restore?

Comment: That's an option, though it doesn't help future updates

Comment: I am having the same issue, reinstalling Virtual Box does not help

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, finally, though I don't think it is a long term solution.

```
uninstall virtual box
delete .vagrant directory (..../vagrant/.vagrant)
re-install virtual box version 5.0.20 (this is an older version)
vagrant up
```